# Deleting a Reference in a MongoEngine ListField?

Tags: mongodb, orm, mongoengine

I have  Mongoengine ORM that maps the following relationship, (simplified):

```
class UserInfo(mg.Document):
    username = mg.StringField()
    allcharacters = mg.ListField(mg.ReferenceField("Character"))
    pass

class Character(mg.Document):
    charid = mg.IntField()
    pass
```

A User refers to an array of references to Character's. The problem is that when I access the User's allcharacter array and delete a reference:

```
for x in db.UserInfo.objects(username = session["user"])[0].allcharacters:
    if x.charid == someint:
        x.delete()
```

The document in question gets deleted but the reference in the array remains, pointing to a document that no longer exists.

I tried to

```
allcharacters = mg.ListField(
    mg.ReferenceField("Character"), reverse_delete_rule=mg.CASCADE)
```

but that seems to do nothing.

How do I delete the entry in the ListField of an ListField(ReferenceField) in Mongoengine?

Answer (score 3):

To guide future generations:
In order to delete the reference element from an array once the actual reference has been deleted, requires using the `$pull` operation.

```
char = db.Character.objects()[0]
objid = char.pk
char.delete()

user = db.UserInfo.objects().update_one(pull__allcharacters=objid)
```

Get a variable that points to the specific reference you want to delete. Use the `.pk` attribute to get it's ObjectId. You can now delete the document. To delete the reference in the array within the document, it's a pull query such that if the `objid` is in the array of `allcharacters`

May the future generation find this a solace.